# Import MySQL db into MS Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to import a MySQL schema into a db in Microsoft Azure, I have read I need to have the file with the schema in BACPAC format, after that the file can be uploaded and imported in MS Azure.

How can a .sql file be converted into BACPAC format?

Comment: you may be able to import it to azure using php http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394110.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typed [`mysql to azure` into Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+to+azure) and found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/23/migrating-from-mysql-to-sql-azure-using-ssma.aspx):

> ## Migrating from MySQL to SQL Azure Using SSMA
>
> In this blog post, I will describe how to setup your trial SQL Azure account for your migration project, create a “free” database on SQL Azure and walkthrough differences in the process of using SSMA to migrate the tables from the MySQL Sakila sample database to SQL Azure.
>
> ...
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>
> ...
>
> [image: Screenshot]

You can download *Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL* from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28764).

Comment: But if my web application is accessing MySQL at the moment, then it won't work on Azure, as now the db has been converted to SQL Server

Comment: Savior!
If you don't get it to work at first, right click on your MySQL database and "Convert Schema". You'll see a new schema in the SQL Azure database -- right click and "Synchronize with Database". Then back up to MySQL database to right click on it and "Migrate Data" :))